# How to bind list of abstract classes from local.settings.json?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, azure-functions

Suppose below is my class

```
public class ProjectConfig {
  public List<Animal> Animals {get;set;}
  public ProjectConfig() {
    Animals = new List<Animal>();
  }
}
```

I have `Bird` and `Cat` inheriting `Animal` class.

```
public abstract class Animal {
   public int legs {get;set;}
}

public class Bird:Animal {
  public string beakColor {get;set;}
}

public class Cat:Animal {
}
```

local.settings.json

```
"values": {
  "ProjectConfig:Animals:[0]:legs":"4",
  "ProjectConfig:Animals:[1]:legs":"2",
  "ProjectConfig:Animals:[1]:beakColor":"yellow"
}
```

```
builder.Services.AddOptions<ProjectConfig>()
                .Configure<IConfiguration>((option, configuration) =>
                {
                    configuration.GetSection("ProjectConfig").Bind(option);
                });
```

When I consume `ProjectConfig`, `Animals` is just empty list.

Comment: Can you share the class `Animal` code?

Comment: I have just updated the code. thanks!

Comment: You can't. They have to be concrete classes.

Comment: `Animal` is an abstract class, so it can not be initialized directly... and configuration initialization logic does not know the about the classes which inherits the `Animal` class so it will not magically create objects of those classes. I don't think there is a way around this... You will need to use concrete classes here.. @chiaDev

Comment: could i possibly specify the derived class name and then manually map it in the startup?

Comment: You can't. You need to rethink your approach.

Comment: https://andrewlock.net/using-multiple-instances-of-strongly-typed-settings-with-named-options-in-net-core-2-x/

Comment: https://andrewlock.net/how-to-use-the-ioptions-pattern-for-configuration-in-asp-net-core-rc2/